# Why might Google analytics behavior flow show visitors going from the homepage to a page that isn't linked from it?

Tags: google-analytics, links

I was looking at my behavior flow chart and I noticed that people are going from the homepage to a page that can't be accessed from the homepage at all.

What do you think could be the reason for this showing up on the chart?

Comment: Are these direct, organic or referral sources?

Comment: Direct - the first interaction page shows that traffic is coming straight from the homepage as the starting page. There aren't any links with that first interaction page anywhere on the homepage.

Comment: You might want to look at your web logs.  Someone might be querying your sitemap with their browser to view your pages and then navigating to other pages.  Unusual yes, but I've done that before.